# how to create single user key using inno setup for my desktop app

Tags: php

I have created a desktop app using Inno setup from php code. i have add serial key which is same to each user. but i'm not able to create single user key unique to each user. Is it possible to create single user key using inno setup.

Comment: Yes, use `rand(1000000, 9999999)`

Comment: But Is it possible to change key dynamically for new users when they install my app. So that once he enters that serial number and installs it, I need to change the value of the previous serial number.